# Escape javadoc character sequences in javadoc <pre> code snippet

Tags: java, javadoc

Given the following javadoc documented snippet:

```
/**
* Code example:
*
  <pre>
    // call foo like this:
    foo("/**/*/?.txt");
  </pre>
*
*/
public void foo(String glob) {
}
```

How can I properly escape character sequences like `/**` and `*/` in a `<pre>` block in javadoc?

I've tried `{@code}` and backslashes, but either the escape characters show in the resulting javadoc or the code does not compile because the javadoc block ends prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&#47;` instead of `/`, which will not end the JavaDoc comment.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work, because everything was wrapped in `{@code}`. Works fine without `{@code}` 